# Intercepting XHR made from web worker?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, intercept

I am debugging a web app and I have no access to modify it. I have been using something like this (on chrome dev console, also tried creating a simple extension to run the code):

```
(function(open) {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
            console.log('log stuff');
        }, false);
        open.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

For logging purposes, but I ran into a problem. There's a part of the code that looks like this:

```
var worker = new Worker('js/worker.js');
worker.addEventListener('message', function(data) {
    doStuffWith(data)
}, false);
```

worker.js is a simple xhr that `postMessage()` the result of a get request like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/url', false);
xhr.send();
var msg = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
postMessage(msg);
```

The problem is that the first piece of code is not catching this request.

How can I "intercept" it to add it to my logs?

Comment: `worker.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open`, adjust `console.log('log stuff');` to `postMessage()` if global scope is `Worker`?

Comment: Can you modify `Worker` code?

Comment: No I don't have access to any of the code to modify, I could always "proxify" the request and use my own files but I want to keep it simpler so I am just running stuff on dev console/simple extension. Also var worker is inside a function so I can't even access that injecting code on the site.

Comment: _"No I don't have access to any of the code to modify"_ You can try using `PerformanceObserver` or an extension. [`WorkerGlobalScope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope) is different from `window` scope